# why my jenkins has no Pass job parameters as Gradle properties choice?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

When I want to add automatic parameters  to gradle  task  ,there was no choice to click!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9oRV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pass all job parameters as Project parameters should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this.

```
#gradle.properties

VERSION_CODE=328
VERSION_NAME=1.5.8


#module build.gradle

  versionCode project.VERSION_CODE as int
  versionName project.VERSION_NAME
```